# Форматирование строк с#

Tags: c#

Почему у меня не выводится массив schedule в самом конце программы?С самим массивом точно проблем нет,проходился foreach и все элементы вывело. А когда пытаюсь вывести массив с помощью форматирования, то ничего не выводится. Матрица у меня размера NxM. N процессоров и M заданий.

```
 static List<List<int>> Schedule(int[] tasks, int N, int M)
    {
        // Первый этап
        var rnd = new Random();
        var firstSchedule = new List<List<int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            firstSchedule.Add(new List<int>());
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            var pi = rnd.Next(0, N);
            firstSchedule[pi].Add(tasks[j]);
        }
       
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
    // Второй этап
    while (true)
    {
        // Шаг 1
        var loadTimes = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            loadTimes[i] = firstSchedule[i].Sum();
        }

        // Шаг 2
        int maxLoadIndex = 0;
        int minLoadIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (loadTimes[i] > loadTimes[maxLoadIndex])
            {
                maxLoadIndex = i;
            }
            if (loadTimes[i] < loadTimes[minLoadIndex])
            {
                minLoadIndex = i;
            }
        }
      int  delta = loadTimes[maxLoadIndex] - loadTimes[minLoadIndex];

        // Шаг 3
        bool isSwapped = false;
        for (int k = 0; k < firstSchedule[maxLoadIndex].Count && !isSwapped; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < firstSchedule[minLoadIndex].Count && !isSwapped; l++)
            {
                if (firstSchedule[maxLoadIndex][k] - firstSchedule[minLoadIndex][l] < delta &&
                    firstSchedule[maxLoadIndex][k] > firstSchedule[minLoadIndex][l])
                {
                    isSwapped = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!isSwapped)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Шаг 4
        var temp = firstSchedule[maxLoadIndex];
        firstSchedule[maxLoadIndex] = firstSchedule[minLoadIndex];
        firstSchedule[minLoadIndex] = temp;
    }

    return firstSchedule;
}

int N = 4, M = 7;
var schedule=Schedule(new int[7] { 5, 10, 15, 7, 4, 22, 5 }, N,M);

Console.WriteLine("Матрица расписания:");
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    Console.Write("{0}\t", "p" + j);
Console.WriteLine();
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < schedule.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < schedule[i].Count; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}\t", schedule[j][i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
catch { }
Console.WriteLine("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < schedule.Count; i++)
{
    Console.Write("{0}\t", schedule[i].Sum());
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде всё правильно, {0} меняется на p0, p1..., что вы ожидаете увидеть в консоли?

Comment: `schedule[j][i]` неверный порядок.

Comment: Да я хотел там выводить все по столбикам,но лучше будет по строкам. У меня еще считаются суммы строк. Мне хочется чтобы они ровно отображались в одном месте.Но из-за того,что в каждой строке разное кол-во элементов,сумма оказывается либо левее,либо правее.Можно это как-то исправить.Там немножко другой код,т.к выводил другую матрицу.Приложил скриншот к вопросу